# Cannot use 'Object' as class name as it is reserved

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to update my composer with **composer self-update** but i get this error

```
composer self-update
Updating to version 6034c2af01e264652a060e57f1e0288b4038a31a.
    Downloading: 100%         

Fatal error: Cannot use 'Object' as class name as it is reserved in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/justinrainbow/json-schema/src/JsonSchema/Constraints/Object.php on line 18
```

I'm using macOS 10.15.2

trying to see other answers but cannot find anything related to this.

Answer (score 2):

I would venture to guess that you are using:

1. A version of composer that is 5+ years old, which is when that class was renamed.

   - https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema/commit/dc310ac54cd3323587ba33784a4489a1451b8faf
2. A version of PHP>=7.2, which is when `Object` became a reserved word.

   - https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.other-reserved-words.php

I would suggest deleting composer.phar and [downloading a fresh one](https://getcomposer.org/download/). You will not lose anything by doing so.

Comment: In terminal check composer -V and php -v and then upgrade/downgrade on of them